# Gluster_Volume module in ansible

Tags: ansible

Request you to help me on the following Issue

I am writing a High available LAMPAPP on UBUNTU 14.04 with ansible (on my home lab). All the tasks are getting excecuted till the glusterfs installation however creating the Glusterfs Volume is a challenge for me since a week. If is use the command moudle the glusterfs volume is getting created

```
  - name: Creating the Gluster Volume
      command: sudo gluster volume create var-www replica 2 transport tcp server01-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick server02-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick02/brick
```

But if i use the GLUSTER_VOLUME module i am getting the error

```
- name: Creating the Gluster Volume
  gluster_volume:
      state: present
      name: var-www
      bricks: /server01-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick,/server02-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick02/brick
      replicas: 2
      transport: tcp
      cluster:
         - server01-private
         - server02-private
      force: yes
  run_once: true
```

The error is

```
"msg": "error running gluster (/usr/sbin/gluster --mode=script volume add-brick var-www replica 2 server01-private:/server01-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick server01-private:/server02-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick02/brick server02-private:/server01-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick server02-private:/server02-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick02/brick force) command (rc=1): internet address 'server01-private:/server01-private' does not conform to standards\ninternet address 'server01-private:/server02-private' does not conform to standards\ninternet address 'server02-private:/server01-private' does not conform to standards\ninternet address 'server02-private:/server02-private' does not conform to standards\nvolume add-brick: failed: Host server01-private:/server01-private is not in 'Peer in Cluster' state\n"
```

}

May i know the mistake i am committing

Answer (score 0):

The `bricks:` declaration of Ansible `gluster_volume` module requires *only* the path of the brick. The nodes participating in the volume are identified as `cluster:`.

The `<hostname>:<brickpath>` format is required for the `gluster` command line. However when you use the [Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gluster_volume_module.html), this is not required.

So your task should be something like:

```yaml
- name: Creating the Gluster Volume
  gluster_volume:
    name: 'var-www'
    bricks: '/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick,/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick02/brick'
    replicas: '2'
    cluster:
      - 'server01-private'
      - 'server02-private'
    transport: 'tcp'
    state: 'present'
```